# Parse JSON string with inconsistent field names

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am having trouble in deserializing the following JSON structure. Each node contains a ID and multiple language code with values. The number of language attributes is not consistent. But I need those values as a list of objects which has a Language field and a Value field.

```
       [{  
          "id":"w_312457",
          "eng":"deep-fat frying",
          "ger":"Frittieren"
       },
       {  
          "id":"w_312458",
          "fre":"frying",
          "ger":"braten (in Öl)"
       },
       {  
          "id":"w_312477",
          "ger":"perfekt gewürzte und abgestimmte Soße "
      }]
```

I tried using `JsonPropertyName` attribute and I got the ID value. But for lang nodes, I dont know what name I can specify. Following is my CLR object,

```
 public class Word
 {
    public string Id { get; set; } // This is working

    // What can I specify here. I need a list of objects each with a lang code and value.
 }
```

Comment: Have you made any inroads with any approaches yet?  It sounds like you want a `List<Dictionary<string,string>>`, then parse the dictionaries afterwards.

Comment: I would be tempted to change the structure of your JSON slightly. So the definitions would be in any array:  `"id": "w_313223", "translations": [ { "lang": "ger", "value": "perfekt gewürzte und abgestimmte Soße" } ]` do you see what I mean? That way the array can have `x` amount of translations in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**

One approach would be to simply adding all the values and checking if they exist. For example this is the class that contains all the language values:

```
public class Word
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string eng { get; set; }
    public string ger { get; set; }
    public string fre { get; set; }
}
```

And you get the list such as:

```
var words  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Word>>(json);
```

Of course this assumes there are only 3 languages and more will not be added (which never happens!)

**Method 2:**

As shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net) thread, you can deserialize to a list of dictionary objects like this:

```
var words = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);
```

And you can access all keys and values like this:

```
foreach (var word in words)
{
    foreach (var key in word.Keys)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"value for the key {key} is {word[key]}");
    }
}
```

This will produce the following result:

> value for the key id is w_312457
>
> value for the key eng is deep-fat frying
>
> value for the key ger is Frittieren
>
> value for the key id is w_312458
>
> value for the key fre is frying
>
> value for the key ger is braten (in Öl)
>
> value for the key id is w_312477
>
> value for the key ger is perfekt gewürzte und abgestimmte Soße